# Why are feature branch builds not triggered after the Branch Specification in the VCS Root was changed?

Tags: teamcity, plasticscm

TeamCity 2019.1.4, VCS is Plastic SCM.

I updated an existing build configuration in a project (Project A) with a default branch of `/main`, to include a branch specification (which it did not have before) of `+:(/main/*)`, so that feature/other branches would also be picked up and built. But no commits on the feature/other branches trigger a build, only commits to `/main`.

The VCS Trigger is fairly standard, the branch filter there is just `+:*`.

There is a different project (Project B) in the same TeamCity instance, with the same VCS Root configuration (obviously with a different Repository), which behaves as expected and the feature/other branches are built, as well as the `/main` branch. This project and build configuration were setup like this when it was created.

I cannot see any difference in the TeamCity UI between the two configurations, yet they behave differently? How can this be?

Comment: Hi, if you reach us at support@codicesoftware.com we can help you to debug the configuration and try to understand why one project is working bot not the other.

Comment: Are you able to show some of the values in your VCS root that is not kicking off the feature builds? I do not know if there is enough info here to provide any helpful answers.

Comment: @JeffGruenbaum I already have? The default branch of ```/main``` and the branch specification of ```+:(/main/*)```. Not sure what other values you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new VCS Root with the exact same configuration and using it in the project resolved this problem.

Still unsure whether this is an issue with TeamCity or with the Plastic plugin, I suspect the former.